# SQL Multiple SUM analysis

Tags: sql, postgresql

(First, sorry for my English I'm writing this from France)

I've read a lot of solutions here, but I'm quite lost!

Here's the problem: I've three tables
`Budgets`, `Invoice`, and `Paiements`

The relations are 1 to many between `Invoice` and `Budgets`, (there's always at least one budget) and, 0 to many between `Invoice` and `Paiements` i.e. (the Invoice can be not paid).

I'm trying to find any Invoice which is not paid OR partially paid!

Let's have an example

[image]

Then... I've written an `SQL statement` for it as the following:

```
Select sum(budget.amount) as m1, sum(Paiements.amount),budget.code 
from 
budget left outer join paiements 
on 
budget.code=Paiements.code 
group by budget.code
```

I get this answer:

[image]

Now I'm trying to get only where C2 is 0 or C1 not equals C2.

How to modify my SQL statement?

Comment: It's on PostGres SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `Having Clause` to specify conditions that filter which group results should appear in the results.

> The WHERE clause places conditions on the selected columns, whereas the HAVING clause places conditions on groups created by the GROUP BY clause.

So your query will be as the following:

```
Select sum(budget.amount) as m1, coalesce(sum(paiements.amount),0), budget.code
from 
budget left outer join paiements 
on 
budget.code = paiements.code 
group by budget.code
Having coalesce(sum(paiements.amount),0) = 0 
or sum(budget.amount) <> coalesce(sum(paiements.amount),0)
```

The use of `coalesce(sum(paiements.amount),0)` function is to replace the `null` values with zeros.

See a demo from [db-fiddle.](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/k3tzyX4hn1cTyinbVf4vot/2)

Note: it's a good practice to use aliases for the tables and columns in your query, doing so makes the query more readable.
Consider the following query:

```
select sum(B.amount) c1, coalesce(sum(P.amount),0) c2 ,B.code c3
from 
budget B left outer join paiements P
on 
B.code=P.code 
group by B.code
having coalesce(sum(P.amount),0) =0 
Or sum(B.amount) <> coalesce(sum(P.amount),0)
```